# What does it mean when a structure is used as a function type

Tags: c, function, structure

So we started doing structures in C and have gotten some examples of using structures and functions.
Most are void functions, but some functions, instead of a data type, have a structure name. For example:

```
Student* ucitajStudenteTxt(int* koliko)
```

where "Student" is a previously declared structure.

I'd just like to know what that type of declaration means, and what benefits would it have, since I couldn't find an answer in the presentations or online.

Comment: The function returns a pointer to a `Student` struct

Comment: “instead of a data type, have a structure name” — Structures *are* data types.

Comment: My guess is that they used the Student* so that you can return a a pointer to an array of students.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Student *` is used to return a pointer to the type `Student`. If we simply use `Student`, it returns the type `Student` itself.
You asked, in a comment, what is the purpose of using a pointer variable instead of the type itself. Pointers have a lot of use cases. For example, if you want to modify a variable passed as an argument into a function (pass by address), you have to use pointer variables.
In your case without the complete context of the program, we cannot say why a pointer is used.

Sometimes dealing with pointer variables is so much easier. For example, when dealing with a linked list data structure, using a pointer over the type itself for each node is much easier to handle.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `Student` is a valid type, then `Student *` is the type "pointer to `Student`".

So it's a type as well, just not one of the standard types of C.

Comment: What would be the purpose of using that type instead of the standard ones?

Comment: @Neptune The same as returning any kind of value? I don't know what the `ucitajStudenteTxt` is supposed to do, but it might somehow create a `Student` structure instance, then return a pointer to that structure instance, so the caller can use the structure in some way.